# MacOS Instruments returns empty profiles for CPU cycles

Tags: macos, performance, profiling, instruments, performancecounter

I was using Instruments on MacOS Catalina 10.15.7 (19H15) to profile my simple C++ program "sort". My intention was to get the CPU cycles for each assembly instruction like the "perf annotate" shown below: [image]. From Instruments app, I picked the "Cycles" event from the Recording Options pane shown as below:
[image]

Then I hit "Record" to start profiling. But nothing showed up in the "Details" pane even after I stopped profiling:
[image]

How do I get the perf annotation on MacOS? Thank you very much.

Comment: Does anything appear in the Details pane when you select the Counters instrument from the instrument list above the Details pane? I notice in your screenshot you have a thread selected. I did a test profile with the Counters instrument, and I had to select the Counters instrument instead of a thread to get anything to appear in the Details pane.

Comment: Thank you @MarkSzymczyk Yes you're right. Selecting Counters showed the profile.